# How to get rosjava generate classes instead of interfaces?

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I followed the rosjava tutorials for 'unofficial messages' for Hydro. It all works, but I get an interface .java file instead of a class. For example:

scip_api/msgs/Alarm.msg:

```
string alarm_name
string data_name
```

scip_api/build/generated-src/scip_api/Alarm.java:

```
package scip_api;

public interface Alarm extends org.ros.internal.message.Message {
  static final java.lang.String _TYPE = "scip_api/Alarm";
  static final java.lang.String _DEFINITION = "string alarm_name\nstring data_name";
  java.lang.String getAlarmName();
  void setAlarmName(java.lang.String value);
  java.lang.String getDataName();
  void setDataName(java.lang.String value);
}
```

While for the std_msgs types, the generated .java file is a class (at least for String.msg it is)

What did I do wrong ? I used the released ros-hydro-rosjava packages for Ubuntu 12.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/133286/how-to-get-rosjava-generate-classes-instead-of-interfaces-?/) by [psoetens](https://answers.ros.org/users/1336/psoetens/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2014-02-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The post above was confused by http://answers.ros.org/question/10276/rosjavapure-pubsub-tutorial/ which probably refers to an older version where this was possible.

The getting started guide of rosjava here: http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/getting_started.html#messages

explains how to instantiate messages using a factory. All messages are interfaces on purpose.

---

Originally posted by [psoetens](https://answers.ros.org/users/1336/psoetens/) with karma: 76 on 2014-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0